# Error when call a action come from a other file on react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

On index.js

```
... 
import ButtonContent from './ButtonContent';
...
class App extends Component {
   onAlert() {
      alert("Test")
   } 
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <ButtonContent/>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
```

file ButtonContent.js

```
...
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
...
const ButtonContent = () => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
    this.onAlert();
  }}>
    <Text>Alert</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
export default withNavigation(ButtonContent);
```

Error this.onAlert() is not function. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `onAlert` function to `ButtonContent` component,

```
<ButtonContent onAlert={this.onAlert}/>
```

And then you can call this function using `props`,

```
const ButtonContent = (props) => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onAlert}>
    <Text>Alert</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@ravibagul91 thanks your ideas, I has fixed ok. This is my edited code

file ButtonContent.js

```
type Props = {
  onAlert: Function
};

const ButtonContent =  ({ onAlert }: Props): Object => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onAlert}>
    <Text>Alert</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

And index.js

```
<ButtonContent onAlert={this.onAlert}/>
```